# Выбрать строку с максимальным значением по последней дате

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица

```
| id | user_id | sum      | created_at          |
|----|---------|----------|---------------------|
| 1  | 3       | 3434.333 | 2018-02-06 16:52:00 |
| 2  | 4       | 2222.333 | 2018-02-06 16:52:00 |
| 3  | 5       | 4414.44  | 2018-02-06 16:52:00 |
| 4  | 3       | 3332.32  | 2018-02-06 18:55:00 |
| 5  | 4       | 4144.24  | 2018-02-06 18:55:00 |
| 6  | 5       | 2322.22  | 2018-02-06 18:55:00 |
```

Необходимо вытянуть строку с максимальным sum по наибольшему created_at

В данном случае это будет строка с id = 5 (4, 4144.24, 2018-02-06 18:55:00)

Мои попытки

```
select `user_id`,`created_at`, max(sum) from `data` where created_at IN ( SELECT max(created_at) FROM data )
```

Но он не верно выводит поля user_id, created_at (выводит всегда первое значение из max(created_at))

Comment: Сортировка по дате и по цене с лимитом 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL:

```
select top 1 * from data order by [created_at] desc, [sum] desc
```

MySql:

```
select * from data order by `created_at` desc, `sum` desc limit 1
```